# Find Specific Rows

Tags: sql, semantics

I'm trying to build a rather specific query to find a set of user_ids based on topics they have registered to.
Unfortunately it's not possible to refactor the tables so I have to go with what I've got.

Single table with user_id and registration_id
I need to find all user_ids that have a registration_id of (4 OR 5) AND NOT 1

Each row is a single user_id/registration_id combination.
My SQL skills aren't the best, so I'm really scratching my brain.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your criteria is confusing to me.  If the registration id must be 4 or 5, why are you checking to see if it is not one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
        FROM    registrations
        ) ro
WHERE   user_id IN 
        (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    registrations ri
        WHERE   ri.registration_id IN (4, 5)
        )
        AND user_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    registrations ri
        WHERE   ri.registration_id = 1
        )
```

Most probably, `user_id, registration_id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` in your table. If it's not, then create a composite index on `(user_id, registration_id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: That's the trick.  I was very close after all.  Missed the layout for the select distinct part

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the best way to do it (my SQL skills aren't the best either), but should do the job:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table AS t
WHERE registration_id IN (4, 5)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id
                    FROM table
                    WHERE user_id = t.user_id
                        AND registration_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with eliminating duplicates of user_id:

```
SELECT  user_id
        FROM    registrations
        WHERE   registration_id IN (4, 5)
except
SELECT  user_id
        FROM    registrations
        WHERE   registration_id =1
```

One use of a table:

```
select user_id from registrations
where registration_id <=5
group by  user_id
having MIN(registration_id)>1 and MAX(registration_id)>= 4
```